# Training model in Keras(TF backend) with GPU

Tags: keras, tensorflow, gpu

I want to train my custom dataset for licence plate detection. I have 2000 image for this. First, I trained my labelling dataset in Keras (TF backend) with CPU.

> optimizer : Adam, learning rate : 0.01 , batch size = 64,
>   iteration:100000

In this case, my training period exceeded 10 days, loss is 10. When I tested the model could detect licence plates. (acc : 80%)

Then, I decided to train with gpu because of the training period is too long.

I uninstall tensorflow and I install tensorflow-gpu(1.13), Cuda(10.0) and Cudnn(7.4) and I added these codes:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

In this time, when I use the same values (Adam, lr=0.01, itr=100000, bs=64), loss value decreases very fast every iteration (loss begins with 210 and ends 0.000000). The training ends in four-five hours. But when I tested, my model could not detect any licence plate.

I try to change values. I did learning rate = 0.000001, iteration =3000 so that the loss is 0.7, training ends 10-20 minutes, but model detects very wrong. (and I know this number is very bad for learning rate)

My GPU : GeForce RTX 2080

How can I optimize these numbers, where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: The fact you perform the training on a CPU or on a GPU wouldn't affect the results, more over from 80% to 0%. It seems to me, than when you are using the GPU, you are not testing the model with the learned weights... Are you sure you are not closing the tf.Session() or you are not restoring the weights?

Comment: thank you, I think so too, the training on a CPU or on a GPU souldn't affect the results. but according to my results it does. actually I dont understand why is the final loss value is different when training with Gpu and Cpu with the same values? i think my learning rate and batch size values are wrong, because when I changed these numbers training with gpu, my model can detect something but wrong, at least it tries. (so, the problem should not relate to weights) i dont know how to optimize learning rate and batch size training with gpu.